# Application of # for the $n^{th}$ derivative

Tags: map, slot, calculus-and-analysis

Let's say that I have

```
x^2+x
```

Is there a way to map $x$ to the first derivative of a function and $x^2$ to the second derivative of the same function? According to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html, I know that I can change

```
x /. x -> D[#, {y, 1}] &[a[y, z]]
x^2 /. x^2 -> D[#, {y, 2}] &[a[y, z]]
```

to yield the first and second derivatives of $a(y,z)$, respectively. I also know that I can use

```
x^2+x/. x^2 -> D[#, {y, 2}] &[a[y, z]] /. x -> D[#, {y, 1}] &[a[y, z]]
```

but if I have say, a polynomial of degree 70, manually telling Mathematica to do this is highly inefficient. Is there a method, such that, for $x^n$, I can tell Mathematica to map $x^n$ to the $n^{th}$ derivative of a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{x, x^2, x^2 + x} /. x^n_. :> Derivative[n, 0][a][y, z]
```

Comment: Sorry for short answer, was in hurry, if anything is unclear just ask.

Answer (score 8):

Rule-replacement with `x^n_. :> Derivative[n,0][a][y,z]` (as done in Kuba's answer) has two drawbacks: if your polynomial has a constant term, then it will not be replaced by the zero-th derivative `a[y,z]`, and if your polynomial is not expanded the result is incorrect.  Namely, `(1+x)(2+x)` becomes `(1+a'[y,z])(2+a'[y,z])` rather than `2a[y,z]+3a'[y,z]+a''[y,z]` (here I use `'` to denote derivative with respect to the first variable).

One option is to multiply by `x` and `Expand`:

```
{x, x^2, x^2 + x, (1 + x) (2 + x)} //
  (Expand[x #] /. x^n_. :> Derivative[n-1, 0][a][y, z] &)

(*{Derivative[1, 0][a][y, z],
   Derivative[2, 0][a][y, z],
   Derivative[1, 0][a][y, z] + Derivative[2, 0][a][y, z],
   2*a[y, z] + 3*Derivative[1, 0][a][y, z] + Derivative[2, 0][a][y, z]}*)
```

Another option which I find more natural is to get the `CoefficientList`, then rebuild the expression.  But this does not thread nicely over lists of polynomials (here I used `x^2+x`).

```
Total@MapIndexed[#1 Derivative[#2[[1]] - 1, 0][a][y, z] &,
  CoefficientList[x + x^2, x]]
```